# Get Count of column depends on Month sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I need to get count of each month data with two condition, "where status =1 and status = 2".
I am getting result with one of the two condition successfully. but i need both data at a time. 
I have used

```
"select count(status),strftime("%m", date) as 'date' from TABLE_NAME where status='1'  group by strftime("%m-%Y", date)"
```

this giving me the result correctly, but how can i get both conditions data at single query. I needed this to set monthly graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `AND status='2'` so you have `WHERE status='1' AND status='2'`.

Further reading: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_select_query.htm

**EDIT**

This is a bit more difficult than what I am used but it should be pretty close to this.

```
SELECT count(status),strftime("%m", date),
    sum(case when status = '1' then 1 else 0 end) date_status_1,
    sum(case when status = '2' then 1 else 0 end) date_status_2
from TABLE_NAME
group by strftime("%m-%Y", date)
```

Comment: But it will give me the Complete count of both status 1 and 2.how can i differentiate them

Comment: So you want the result of the query you posted but then you want the result you would obtain if you did it again with the `where` condition equal to `2` right?

Comment: I mean i want reasult for example in 'May' month suppose there are 3 numbers of status=1 and 8 numbers of status=2. In my graph i need to show bar graph for 1 & 2. But if i apply AND clause it will directly give me the count 8+3=11 right? But i dont want it in that way..

Comment: awesome. Thanks bro. this is what i wanted.